# Which one is correct in present perfect?

Tags: american-english, present-perfect

I have confusion about the following sentences.

> 1. I have never seen these flowers before (what have they been called).
> 2. I have never seen these flowers before (what are they called).
> 3. I have never seen these flowers before (what are they being called).

Comment: Why are you marking the second sentence with brackets? They are really two completely separate sentences, and you should separate them with a full stop. And because they are separate sentences they can have independent tenses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence and the third one seem wrong. I think it is right to say "I have never seen these flowers before. What are they called".

Comment: Also note that this answer correctly makes *flowers* plural to agree with *these*, but it is also valid to refer to a single instance of the flower or the type of flower as:  "*I have never seen this flower before.  What is it called?*"

Answer (score -1):

I think Second one is correct.

> 1. I have never seen these flower before (what are they called).

**Update :**

Consider the first answer the original answer posted by me was wrong so I have updated to correct answer

Comment: Thanks rebel, now the only thing wrong with this answer is the agreement between *these* and *flower*.  However, once that is fixed, then what will be the difference between your updated answer and Khan's original answer?